# User friendly way to import / share files to your iOS app

Tags: ios, user-experience, file-sharing

The app needs document files from users. Document files are usually found in PC / emails right? What is the most intuitive / user friendly way to get those data from your iOS app? No need to consider effort or how long it will take, the focus is in the user experience.

I have the ff ideas:

1. Import / Export data via email

   - Read an article [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app). So you will ask your users to email files to him/herself and your app will get the data? Still a bit complicated, but is this the best way?
2. iTunes

   - Drag and drop files from Desktop to your app using iTunes. Imho, not very intuitive but I could be wrong.
3. Provide web screen for users to upload their files to server.

   - This is a bit okay, but we want to lessen Desktop / PC interaction.
4. Provide a server to accept files from email.

   - The difference from Item #1 is you will ask user to email it to your specific email address and the server will store it and the app will connect to the server to get the files of course with all the permissions / etc.  Will require significant effort, but it's not an issue, as long as it will enhance user experience.
5. Support other means of data sharing like Dropbox? Any other service that is best for this purpose?
6. [update 1] Wifi / Bluetooth file transfer from PC / other devices to iPad.
7. [update 2] iCloud

Did I miss anything. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you, will add iCloud as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go with #2 iTunes file Sharing

example:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

I prefer this way as you dont need to have internet connection to import, export your files, and is as easy as drag drop,
also you can create folders, and have "protected files in your folders"

Comment: Could you please share the swift4 version of this tutorial ?